# Load balancer configuration in SharePoint

Tags: farm, load-balancing

Can you tell me the steps used to configure web application and alternative access mapping in multi tire farm with load balancer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because each load balancer implementation is different, you'll need to refer to the manufacture documentation. The basic steps are:

1. Point the DNS A record at the virtual IP of the load balancer for the SharePoint FEs.
2. Direct TCP/443 (don't use HTTP in today's world) from the VIP to the target SharePoint FEs.
3. The SharePoint FEs should have the appropriate SSL certificate and FQDN configured for the Web Application AAM/IIS binding.